# "Row-Column Coordinates" of a Character in a Block

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, char

Can one find a character in a large set like this based on its "row-column"coordinates?

```
LLLLLLL.L.LL.L.LLLL.LLLLLLL.LLLLL.LLLLLL.LLLLLLL.L.LLL.LLLLLLLL.LLLLLL.LLLLLLLLLLLLLL.LLLLL
        LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL.LLLLLLLLLLLLL.LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL.LLL..LLLLLLLLLL.LLLLLLLLL.LLLL.LLLLL
        LLLLLLLLL.LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL**.**LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL.LLLL..LL.L.LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL.LLLL.
```

The goal is solving [Advent of Code Day 11](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/11) if you know about it or it helps you understand the question.
This is the method of solving the puzzle which involves row-column coordinates:
Given that each line has 91 characters (indices 0-90), and there are three lines here (0,1,2), could the "." within the asterisks be identified as row 2, column 27 (or any combination). The goal is to check each character against the four characters to its left, right, top, and bottom. Maybe there's a better way, but using the approach that this question is about, one could check:

/*
"." rows[2]columns[27] against:

```
rows[1]columns[27] above 
rows[3]columns[27] below, not shown, because the input is very long), 
rows[2]columns[26] left
rows[2]columns[28  right
```

*/

to see if they are an "L" or a "." That part would be simple, but it relies on being able to identify each character as "rows[row],columns[column".

A 2D Array would not work, because each character needs to be in BOTH the row and column arrays. The current approach (very inefficient) for the 92x91 char block is to create 92 arrays of 91 characters each, then put the 92 arrays in a char[][]. When going through a for loop, the row would be the index/char[] in char[][], and using another for loop within, the column would be the index in the char[]. Feasible, but if you name a better way or point out somewhere a better solution is explained, that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWO-DIMENSIONAL ARRAYS were introduced in Subsection 3.8.5, but we haven't done much with them since then. A 2D array has a type such as int[][] or String[][], with two pairs of square brackets. The elements of a 2D array are arranged in rows and columns, and the new operator for 2D arrays specifies both the number of rows and the number of columns. For example,

```
int[][] A;
A = new int[3][4];
```

This creates a 2D array of int that has 12 elements arranged in 3 rows and 4 columns. Although I haven't mentioned it, there are initializers for 2D arrays. For example, this statement creates the 3-by-4 array that is shown in the picture below:

```
int[][]  A  =  {  {  1,  0, 12, -1 },
                  {  7, -3,  2,  5 },
                  { -5, -2,  2, -9 }
               };
```

An array initializer for a 2D array contains the rows of A, separated by commas and enclosed between braces. Each row, in turn, is a list of values separated by commas and enclosed between braces. There are also 2D array literals with a similar syntax that can be used anywhere, not just in declarations. For example,

```
A  =  new int[][] {  {  1,  0, 12, -1 },
                     {  7, -3,  2,  5 },
                     { -5, -2,  2, -9 }
                  };
```

All of this extends naturally to three-dimensional, four-dimensional, and even higher-dimensional arrays, but they are not used very often in practice.

7.5.1  The Truth About 2D Arrays
But before we go any farther, there is a little surprise. Java does not actually have two-dimensional arrays. In a true 2D array, all the elements of the array occupy a continuous block of memory, but that's not true in Java. The syntax for array types is a clue: For any type BaseType, we should be able to form the type BaseType[], meaning "array of BaseType." If we use int[] as the base type, the type that we get is "int[][] meaning "array of int[]" or "array of array of int." And in fact, that's what happens. The elements in a 2D array of type int[][] are variables of type int[]. And remember that a variable of type int[] can only hold a pointer to an array of int. So, a 2D array is really an array of pointers, where each pointer can refer to a one-dimensional array. Those one-dimensional arrays are the rows of the 2D array. A picture will help to explain this. Consider the 3-by-4 array A defined above.
Copied verbatim from [http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html#:~:text=A%202D%20array%20has%20a,and%20the%20number%20of%20columns](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html#:%7E:text=A%202D%20array%20has%20a,and%20the%20number%20of%20columns).

(n.d.). Retrieved December 29, 2020, from http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html